# How to add and remove values from local storage on checkbox click in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

i have dynamic generated list of checkbox, i want to create array with objects.

I wanted to push data in array of objects if **value is true and setItem to localStorage,**
and if **value is false then it will remove objects from local stora**ge

Can anyone help me to optmize my code with expected output.

**Expected output**

```
[
  {
    "key": "Test",
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "key": "Test1",
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "key": "removeItem",
    "value": false
  }
]
```

**Code**

```
  setColumn($event, item) {
    var obj = {}, valueAliasPair = [];
    if (item.tabelHeader.data != '' && $event.checked === true) {
      obj['key'] = item.tabelHeader.data;
      obj['value'] = $event.checked;
      valueAliasPair.push(obj);
      localStorage.setItem('AvailableAmt', JSON.stringify(valueAliasPair));
    }
    if (item.tabelHeader.data != '' && $event.checked === false) {     
      localStorage.removeItem('AvailableAmt', obj['key']);
    }
    console.log(valueAliasPair, "valueAliasPair");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

```js
setColumn($event, item) {
    let valueAliasPair = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("AvailableAmt") || "[]");

    if (item.tabelHeader.data != "") {
        if ($event.checked) {
        valueAliasPair.push({
            key: item.tabelHeader.data,
            value: true,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("AvailableAmt", JSON.stringify(valueAliasPair));
        } else {
        const ind = valueAliasPair.findIndex((x) => x.key === item.tabelHeader.data);
        valueAliasPair.splice(ind, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("AvailableAmt", JSON.stringify(valueAliasPair));
        }
    }

    console.log(valueAliasPair, "valueAliasPair");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove whole JSON, or specific item from array?

Comment: Answer updated, Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No Actually, i want if i click on checkbox than it will create array of object and push this object in local storage.

Comment: and if i unchecked the checkbox then value will be false, and if value is false it will remove object from array and delete it from local storage

Comment: I want you to modify my function to add and remove items in object and update it in local storage on every checked and unchecked checkbox

Comment: Updated answer again.